# Resize on fancybox after submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have the following problem. I have a form that opens in fancybox. After clicking submit, I make my PHP to redirect to a new html "message sent successfully". However, the window size is large, it does not apply a resize after submitting the form. I wonder, how can I give a resize in the fancybox window after submitting the form, to display the message in the right proportions.

Before submit:

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".maskRight").fancybox({
  "width" : 420,
  "height" : 495,
  "autoScale" : false,
  "transitionIn" : "none",
  "transitionOut" : "none",
  "type" : "iframe"
  });
$.fancybox.resize;
});
</script>
```

After Submit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[fancybox docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) -> API Methods:

```
$.fancybox.update()
```

Comment: I had already tested this method. It displays the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj)"

Comment: i believe you are using fancybox 1 and my answer was assuming fancybox 2. my apologies.